# undefined parameters trying to pass a value from flutter to google apps scripts

Tags: flutter, dart, google-apps-script, parameters, undefined

flutter code

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

Future<void> updateCellValue(String value) async {
  const url =
      'https://script.google.com/macros/s/myurl';

  http.Response response = await http.post(
    Uri.parse(url),
    body: {'value': value},
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    },
  );

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // Richiesta inviata correttamente
    print(response.body);
  } else {
    // Errore durante l'invio della richiesta
    print(response.statusCode);
    print(response.body);
  }
}
```

google apps scripts code

```
function doPost(value) {

console.log(value);

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Foglio1');
  var cell = sheet.getRange('A10');
  cell.setValue(value);
}
```

the problem is that i can't pass the body to the parameter of the javascript function, i literally tried everything but the javascript value is undefined

i would like to pass a flutter value to the parameter of a google scripts function

Comment: doPost does not accept parameters.  See [request parameters](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#request_parameters)